# Remove error from mypy for attributes set dynamically in a Python class

Tags: python, mypy

I am using `mypy` to check my Python code.

I have a class where I set dynamically some attributes and `mypy` keep on complaining about it:

```
error:"Toto" has no attribute "age"
```

This is my code:

```
class Toto:
    def __init__(self, name:str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        for attr in ['age', 'height']:
            setattr(self, attr, 0)


toto = Toto("Toto")
toto.age = 10  # "Toto" has no attribute "age" :(
```

Obviously, there could be 3 ways to solve the issue

1. Ignoring the issue with `# type: ignore`: `toto.age = 10  # type: ignore #...`
2. Using `setattr` to set the `age` of `toto`: `setattr(toto, "age", 10)`
3. Setting the attributes explicitly (`self.age = 0` ...)

However, I am looking for a more elegant and systematic way at the class level.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't follow mypy well enough to know whether this is (still, or ever was) the ideal work around, but [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/521) and [this part of the cheatsheet](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html#when-you-re-puzzled-or-when-things-are-complicated) indicate that something like:

```
from typing import Any

class Toto:
    def __init__(self, name:str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        for attr in ['age', 'height']:
            setattr(self, attr, 0)

    def __setattr__(self, name:str, value:Any):
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

toto = Toto("Toto")
toto.age = 10
```

Will allow you to do what you're doing without mypy complaining (which it does, just tested).

`Any` could be more restrictive, but the types will be checked on both `setattr()` and "traditional" `obj.attr = ...` calls, so heads up.

Comment: I read the Cheatsheet many times but my brain is not as efficient at 11 PM ;) Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose of using mypy in the first place? by just making the type of all attributes `Any` you lose a lot of power to do type checking elsewhere, or push headaches into other code