# mypy and django models: how to detect errors on nonexistent attributes

Tags: django, mypy

Consider this model definition and usage:

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):

    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=100)


def do_stuff(user: User) -> None:

    # accessing existing field
    print(user.name.strip())

    # accessing existing field with a wrong operation: will fail at runtime
    print(user.name + 1)

    # acessing nonexistent field: will fail at runtime
    print(user.name_abc.strip())
```

While running `mypy` on this, we will get an error for `user.name + 1`:

```
error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "int")
```

This is fine. But there's another error in the code - `user.name_abc` does not exist and will result in AttributeError in runtime.

However, mypy will not see this because it lets the code access any django attributes, also treating them as `Any`:

```
u = User(name='abc')
reveal_type(user.abcdef)
....

> error: Revealed type is 'Any
```

So, how do I make mypy see such errors?

Comment: It seems that this is related to the Django model class, not yours.
If you are not subclassing Django model you get an error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889677/remove-error-from-mypy-for-attributes-set-dynamically-in-a-python-class#50889782

Comment: @danielfranca exactly. This is related to django models. The question is - how do I work around it.

Answer (score 1):

The flag `--check-untyped-defs` (or `--strict`) reports missing attributes.
Checked with `mypy version 0.740`.
I assume you are using `django-stubs` plugin.

Comment: BTW: I am running mypy 0.770 and I use --disallow-untyped-defs and I am still hitting this issue from time to time.  Did not have time to time. Did not figure out the exact cases yet.