# Is there a way to define in Mypy a Django model reversed field?

Tags: django, django-models, mypy

Suppose you have the following simple models:

```py
class User(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Article(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='articles')
```

I'll have an auto generated field called `articles` in my `User` model. Now, it's not being inferred by Mypy of PyCharm so the IDE warns me about non existing field. Is there a way to define in Mypy that field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889677/remove-error-from-mypy-for-attributes-set-dynamically-in-a-python-class#50889782

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370377/mypy-and-django-models-how-to-detect-errors-on-nonexistent-attributes

Comment: those two would help.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but unfortunatelly they don't solve my problem: the first one is setting the attribute with Any type, the second is ignoring the error, I'd like to autocomplete with the correct type and prevent warnings without setting Mypy to just ignore them